# Android SDK Manager closes instantly

Tags: android, sdk

Can anyone please confirm if android development is not yet supported on windows 7 x64? I downloaded the sdk, but when I tried to launch the sdk and avd manager it fails to launch.

I have set the PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

I am developing on Win 7 x64, but I am using the 32 bit JDK.  I had problems when I tried to use x64 JDK and Android SDK.  Try to use the 32 bit JDK/SDK/Eclipse only.

Answer (score 0):

I have had no problems developing on Win7 x64.